# when i connect unixodbc with node odbc 2.4.6 show "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: node.js, node-odbc, tibero

I use OS ubuntu 18,node.js 14,
unixodbc from doc Ubuntu/Debian: sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev.
I can connect to database tibero with isql Tibero6

`+---------------------------------------+`
`| Connected!                            |`
`|                                       |`
`| sql-statement                         |`
`| help [tablename]                      |`
`| quit                                  |`
`|                                       |`
`+---------------------------------------+`

#odbc.ini

`[ODBC]`
`Trace = 1`
`TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log`
`[Tibero6]`
`Trace=yes`
`TraceFile=/tmp/odbc.log`
`Driver = Tibero_driver`
`Description = Tibero6 ODBC Datasource`
`ConnectionType = Direct`
`SERVER = mYserver`
`PORT = 8629`
`SID = Tibero6`
`User = myuser`
`Password = myPwd`
`Database = myData`
#odbcinst.ini

`[Tibero_driver]`
`Description = Tibero6 ODBC driver`
`Driver = /home/tibero/client/libtbodbc.so`
`Setup = /home/tibero/client/libtbodbc.so`
`Setup = 1`
`File`
`Usage = 1`

but when i use node  ["odbc": "^2.4.6"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc)

`#index.js`

`const  odbc  = require('odbc');`
`const connectionString = {`
`connectionString: "DSN=Tibero6",`

`connectionTimeout: 10,`
`loginTimeout: 10,`
`}`

```
odbc.connect(connectionString, (error, connection) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(connection)
});
```

and when I run $node index.js
it returns
***Segmentation fault (core dumped)***
every time.
I don't know how to fix it please help me.
I expecting to can connect to unixodbc with node  "odbc"